# Testflight beta testing external users needs to install provisioning profile

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, app-store-connect, testflight

I am planning on using TestFlight from next month onwards to beta test my App.

Apple allow 25 internal users and 1000 external users.

Do all 1000 external users needs to register their device in developers account, do they need to install provisioning profile separately, or do they need to install and register on developers accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to register the device. You need to add them to your iTunes Connect under "External Testers". When you need to test a build, you need to upload it and invite the external testers using their mail. Remember, if you are planning to add external build testing, there is also a beta app review by Apple.

Check [Inviting TestFlight Beta Testers](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) for more details.

> **Internal Testers**
>
> Get feedback quickly by sharing your beta builds with up to 25 members
> of your team who have been assigned the Technical or Admin role in
> iTunes Connect. Each member can test on up to 10 devices.
>
> **External Testers**
>
> Once you’re ready, you can invite up to 1,000 users who are not part
> of your development organization to beta test an app that you intend
> for public release on the App Store. Apps made available to external
> testers require a Beta App Review and must comply with the full App
> Store Review Guidelines before testing can begin. A review is required
> for new versions of your app that contain significant changes. Up to
> 10 apps can be tested at a time, internally or externally.

Comment: According to [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH35-SW6) they only have to be Marketer role or higher. Strangely enough, that contradicts the link in the answer - which is also from Apple. So you may want to edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

Since November 13, 2015 there are some changes occurred in iTunesConnect:

> TestFlight Updates  To make your TestFlight experience even better,
>   we’ve made some significant changes. You can now invite up to 2000
>   external testers and up to 25 internal testers per app. You can also
>   test up to 100 apps at the same time for up to 60 days, and submit up
>   to 6 updates per day to your external testers.

So now 2000 external testers can be invited!